# Failed to update metadata for Cloud SQL instance. :Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am following this tutorial: [Connect to Cloud SQL for MySQL from Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-instance-kubernetes).
I have created a cluster. I have created a docker image in the repository. I have created a database. I am able to run my application outside of Kubernetes and it connects to the database. But after deploying application, pods are not in a valid state and I see in the logs of the pod error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: [quizdev:us-central1:my-instance] Failed to update metadata for Cloud SQL instance.
       ...[na:na] 
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
GET https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/quizdev/instances/my-instance/connectSettings
{
  "code": 403,
  "details": [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
      "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
      "domain": "googleapis.com",
      "metadata": {
        "service": "sqladmin.googleapis.com",
        "method": "google.cloud.sql.v1beta4.SqlConnectService.GetConnectSettings"
      }
    }
  ],
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Insufficient Permission",
      "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
       }
  ],
  "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146) ~[google-api-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        ... 

2023-06-14T06:57:49.508Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
```

What could be the issue? What can I check to diagnose the problem?

### Edit

I have created the cluster using this command:

```
  gcloud container clusters create questy-java-cluster \
  --num-nodes 2 \
  --machine-type n1-standard-1 \
  --zone us-central1-c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you create a cluster by default. If you did that, you used the Compute Engine default parameter that you can see here

[image]

Default service account and access scope. If you did that, it's normal you have no access: the minimal scope does not allow the Cloud SQL access.

---

To solve that, you have to select either a user managed service account (the best solution) or still use the default service account but allow full scopes access.

2 solutions to enforce that:

- Either delete and recreate correctly your cluster
- Or, you can create another node pool with the correct parameters.

Comment: I have done an edit showing how I created my cluster. I have done it from Cloud Shell using  'gcloud container clusters create'. Do you know how I can edit my command to create the cluster with appropriate access?

Comment: Yes, add `--scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"` for the full scopes access, or `--service-account "<service account email>"` if you want to use a user managed service account

Comment: I will try it, on the top of that is there a way  to add the  "Cloud SQL access" to the mentioned "Default service account" ?

Comment: The easiest is the full scope usage. If you want to narrow the scopes of your VM in the cluster, you can use that website: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes

Comment: the full scope access dis not solve my issue. I will try to change service account –

Comment: Do you still have the insufficient scope permission? It could be another error

Comment: unfortunately I did not save the error message. I tried the other solution and it was succesfull

Answer (score 0):

Based on accepted answer from @guillaume blaquiere I have

1. created service account, as one of the steps of the tutorial:

```
    gcloud iam service-accounts create gke-quickstart-service-account \
      --display-name="GKE Quickstart Service Account"
```

2. recreated the cluster with service account:

[image]

3. Followed again all steps from the tutorial.